# Make a mistake in result of formula

Tags: vba, excel

Following code is of excel userfrom and gets digit data from textbox and calculate formula corresponding  combobox.but when combobox.text="b" for some value of textbox for example 2, the result is  7.46426393229446E-02  while it must be 0.074662

```
dim a as single

a= val(textbox1)

If ComboBox1.Text = "A" Then

    j = 0.05 * (a) ^ 0.9

ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "B" Then

    j = 0.04 * (a) ^ 0.9

ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "C" Then

    j = 0.064 * (a) ^ 0.75

ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "D" Or ComboBox6.Text = "E" Then

    j = 0.08 * (a) ^ 0.75

Else

    j = 0.05 * (a) ^ 0.75

End If
```

label1=j

Comment: What **exactly** is in Textbox1?

Comment: @rory digit value

Comment: how do you display the value of j, by default it is with the scientific notation i.e. 7.4662e-02 which is 0.074662.

Comment: @h2so4 yes,i understood and i use format(j,"0.0000") function

Comment: @mohagali Thanks for editing

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`0.04 * (a) ^ 0.9`

use

`0.04 * CDec((a) ^ 0.9)` or `CDec(0.04 * (a) ^ 0.9)`

This should solve your problem. So your code will be

```
Dim a As Single
a = Val(textbox1)
If ComboBox1.Text = "A" Then
    j = 0.05 * CDec((a) ^ 0.9)
ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "B" Then
    j = 0.04 * CDec((a) ^ 0.9)
ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "C" Then
    j = 0.064 * ((a) ^ 0.75)
ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "D" Or ComboBox6.Text = "E" Then
    j = 0.08 * CDec((a) ^ 0.75)
Else
    j = 0.05 * CDec((a) ^ 0.75)
End If
```

`CDec` function converts value to Decimal.